# LDAP synchronization in LDAP-Hierarchy (recursive) authentication mode in GeoNetwork

Tags: geonetwork

There are ["LDAP"](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.10.x/en/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/authentication-mode.html#configuring-ldap) and ["LDAP – Hierarchy (recursive)"](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.10.x/en/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/authentication-mode.html#configuring-ldap-hierarchy) authentication modes in GeoNetwork.
There is `ldapSynchronizer` bean in simple LDAP xml, so it is possible to configure and set periodical sync GeoNetwork database with LDAP.

Is it possible to configure synchronization in "LDAP – Hierarchy (recursive)" mode? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that's  works for me:
in case you want to use ldapSynchronizer with LDAP-Hierarchy (recursive) authentication mode you should also turn on simple LDAP mode. So your `config-security.xml` will look like that:

```
  <import resource="config-security-${geonetwork.security.type:default}.xml"/>
  <!--<import resource="config-security-keycloak.xml"/> -->
  <import resource="config-security-ldap.xml"/>
  <import resource="config-security-ldap-recursive.xml"/>
  <!-- <import resource="config-security-ecas.xml"/> -->
  <!--<import resource="config-security-cas.xml"/>-->
  <!--<import resource="config-security-cas-ldap.xml"/>-->
  <!-- <import resource="config-security-cas-database.xml"/> -->
  <!-- <import resource="config-security-shibboleth.xml"/>  -->
```

After that you can configure `ldap.sync.` in `config-security.properties`.

Maybe it should be highlighted in [documentation](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/en/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/authentication-mode.html#configuring-ldap-hierarchy).